# Merging results from model.predict() with original pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to merge the results of a `predict` method back with the original data in a `pandas.DataFrame` object.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = load_iris()

# bear with me for the next few steps... I'm trying to walk you through
# how my data object landscape looks... i.e. how I get from raw data 
# to matrices with the actual data I have, not the iris dataset
# put feature matrix into columnar format in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data.data)

# add outcome variable
df['class'] = data.target

X = np.matrix(df.loc[:, [0, 1, 2, 3]])
y = np.array(df['class'])

# finally, split into train-test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# I've got my predictions now
y_hats = model.predict(X_test)
```

To merge these predictions back with the original `df`, I try this:

```
df['y_hats'] = y_hats
```

But that raises:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

I know I could split the `df` into `train_df` and `test_df` and this problem would be solved, but in reality I need to follow the path above to create the matrices `X` and `y` (my actual problem is a text classification problem in which I normalize the *entire* feature matrix before splitting into train and test). How can I align these predicted values with the appropriate rows in my `df`, since the `y_hats` array is zero-indexed and seemingly all information about *which* rows were included in the `X_test` and `y_test` is lost? Or will I be relegated to splitting dataframes into train-test first, and then building feature matrices? I'd like to just fill the rows included in `train` with `np.nan` values in the dataframe.

Comment: I believe that `sklearn` supports `DataFrames` and `Series` as args to `train_test_split` so it should work by passing a sub-section of your df, besides what is returned are the indices so you can use these to index back into your df using `iloc`, see docs: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

your y_hats length will only be the length on the test data (20%) because you predicted on X_test. Once your model is validated and you're happy with the test predictions (by examining the accuracy of your model on the X_test predictions compared to the X_test true values), you should rerun the predict on the full dataset (X). Add these two lines to the bottom:

```
y_hats2 = model.predict(X)

df['y_hats'] = y_hats2
```

**EDIT** per your comment, here is an updated result the returns the dataset with the prediction appended where they were in the test datset

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = load_iris()

# bear with me for the next few steps... I'm trying to walk you through
# how my data object landscape looks... i.e. how I get from raw data 
# to matrices with the actual data I have, not the iris dataset
# put feature matrix into columnar format in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data.data)

# add outcome variable
df_class = pd.DataFrame(data = data.target)

# finally, split into train-test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df,df_class, train_size = 0.8)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# I've got my predictions now
y_hats = model.predict(X_test)

y_test['preds'] = y_hats

df_out = pd.merge(df,y_test[['preds']],how = 'left',left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve my issue of merging only those data that were in `test` to begin with. If you merge back predictions for every row, how do you know which were in the original `test` matrices? For all I know, I could run the lines you added, but have no idea whether the model already saw some of the rows in X (therefore kind of invalidating the whole purpose of train-test).

Comment: @flyingmeatball hi I am trying to do the exact same thing but when you have the y_hats stored as a variable it becomes a numpy array rather then a dataframe that needs to get converted to pandas to do the merge. At that point, the merge on indices can not be done. I am not sure what am I missing?

Comment: y_test['preds'] = y_hats
causing this error [ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1]

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem (almost)

I fixed it this way

```
...
.
.
.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df,df_class, train_size = 0.8)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_hats = model.predict(X_test)

y_hats  = pd.DataFrame(y_hats)

df_out = X_test.reset_index()
df_out["Actual"] = y_test.reset_index()["Columns_Name"]
df_out["Prediction"] = y_hats.reset_index()[0]


y_test['preds'] = y_hats

df_out = pd.merge(df,y_test[['preds']],how = 'left',left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a y_hat dataframe copying indices from X_test then merge with the original data.

```
y_hats_df = pd.DataFrame(data = y_hats, columns = ['y_hats'], index = X_test.index.copy())
df_out = pd.merge(df, y_hats_df, how = 'left', left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

Note, left join will include train data rows.  Omitting 'how' parameter will result in just test data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
y_hats2 = model.predict(X)
df[['y_hats']] = y_hats2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for contributing an answer. I think your answer could be further improved using this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Any chance you can add more context to this?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert y_val or y_test data into the DataFrame.

```
compare_df = pd.DataFrame(y_val)
```

then just create a new column with predicted data.

```
compare_df['predicted_res'] = y_pred_val
```

After that, you can easily filter the data that shows you which data is matching with original prediction based on a simple condition.

```
test_df = compare_df[compare_df['y_val'] == compare_df['predicted_res'] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make a new dataframe and add to it the test data along with the predicted values:

```
data['y_hats'] = y_hats
data.to_csv('data1.csv')
```

Comment: data['y_hats'] = y_hats causing this error [ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1]

Answer (score 0):

```
predicted = m.predict(X_valid)
predicted_df = pd.DataFrame(data=predicted, columns=['y_hat'], 
                            index=X_valid.index.copy())
df_out = pd.merge(X_valid, predicted_df, how ='left', left_index=True, 
                 right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me. It maintains the indexing positions.

```
pred_prob = model.predict(X_test) # calculate prediction probabilities
pred_class  = np.where(pred_prob >0.5, "Yes", "No") #for binary(Yes/No) category
predictions = pd.DataFrame(pred_class, columns=['Prediction'])
my_new_df = pd.concat([my_old_df, predictions], axis =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me:

It consists of building, for each of your folds/iterations, one dataframe which includes observed and predicted values for your test set; this way, you make use of the index (ID) contained in y_true, which should correspond to your subjects' IDs (in my code: 'SubjID').

You then concatenate the DataFrames that you generated (through 5 folds of test data in my case) and paste them back into your original dataset.

I hope this helps!

```
FoldNr = 0
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    FoldNr = FoldNr + 1
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

    # [...] your model

    # performance is measured on test set
    y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)

    # Save predicted values for each test set
    a = pd.DataFrame(y_true).reset_index()
    b = pd.Series(y_pred, name = 'y_pred')
    globals()['ObsPred_df' + str(FoldNr)] = a.join(b)
    globals()['ObsPred_df' + str(FoldNr)].set_index('SubjID', inplace=True)

# Create dataframe with observed and predicted values for all subjects
ObsPred_Concat = pd.concat([ObsPred_df1, ObsPred_df2, ObsPred_df3, ObsPred_df4, ObsPred_df5])

original_df['y_pred'] = ObsPred_Concat['y_pred']
```

Answer (score -3):

you can also use

```
y_hats = model.predict(X)

df['y_hats'] = y_hats.reset_index()['name of the target column']
```